# MySQL: Need to retrieve all records but disregard old entries

Tags: mysql

I have a simple database that keeps track of transactions from multiple players in a game.

When a game is started between two players, a unique **game_id** is generated and stored in a separate database called **game_ids**. In the database I am querying (**game_transactions**) I need the following to happen...

Table **game_transactions** sample data:

```
game_id | home_id | visiting_id | timestamp | ...
   3         1           2        00000001
   4         1           3        00000001
   3         2           1        00000002
   3         1           2        00000003
   4         1           3        00000002
   3         2           1        00000004
   4         1           3        00000003
```

As you can see, when one player completes a turn their game is added to this table. This goes on until the game is completed. What I am trying to do is get all rows when searching by the user_id "WHERE home_id = user_id OR visiting_id = user_id". However this returns ALL the rows for that specific user, I want to limit the query to give the row of data for the MOST RECENT **game_id** by the given **timestamp**. The **timestamp** is an actual UNIX time stamp, but for example purposes this is more readable.

When said and done, this query needs to return the following when **user_id** = 1:

```
game_id | home_id | visiting_id | timestamp | ...
   3         2           1        00000004
   4         1           3        00000003
```

Please let me know if I need to clarify further.

Thank you.

*On a side note, I will be purging the database of entries older than **x** days. But this will be a cron that runs once a day, trying to keep queries to a minimum!*

Comment: Use the Limit Keyword and an Order By clause
[source](http://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/440150-select-one-row-mysql-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT gt.game_id, gt.home_id, gt.visiting_id, gt.timestamp
   FROM game_transactions gt
       INNER JOIN (SELECT game_id, MAX(timestamp) AS MaxTimestamp
                       FROM game_transactions
                       WHERE 1 IN (home_id, visiting_id)
                       GROUP BY game_id) q
           ON gt.game_id = q.game_id
               AND gt.timestamp = q.MaxTimestamp
```

Comment: Up and running! Only conducted ten minutes of testing, but from what I can tell this is EXACTLY what I needed! Thank you so much for you punctuality and the well formatted answer!